# Resize image without Stretcing image

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have an image frame:

[1 http://i48.tinypic.com/wugmc2.png](http://i48.tinypic.com/wugmc2.png)

The image resolution is: 533x300

Using GDI+ I Re-size the image to 300x533:

[image: 2]

Now as you can see it distorted the width/height of the border and shrunken Santa Claus...

Is there a way using GDI+ c# to prevent this distortion of the image frame?

Comment: If you want the image to be exactly this size, it is probably better to split the image in 3. Top and Bottom should always be same size. Or you could draw a simple border and make an overlay of santa.

Comment: did you tried ? any full source code ? not marked answer

Answer (score 2):

Scaling the image will always result into a skewed santa. If that is not what you are looking for, try creating separate images of your santa and the border.

If the border will stay that simple as a red line, I am almost sure that there is a simple control for just drawing red borders in GDI. If you are going to create some christmas border with branches and trees, you need a bit more smaller images to separate this problem.

- Create a separate santa to use as an overlay
- Create separate images for the corners
- Create separate tillable images for vertical and horizontal borders

Then place the images by yourself and tile the images in the centers like so:

[image]

I have never worked with GDI, but this is a general solution for scaling borders.

Comment: nice explanation which needs a lot of work. I will take this into consideration unless i find a more simple way.

Comment: Scaling an image will always result into problems. There is no simpler way if you want the borders to stay exactly like this. If it is ok to have a little bit of scaling, just cut the santa as an overlay and keep the rest as is.